# Gerar logs Apache em arquivos diferentes

Tags: apache

Tenho uma VM rodando um único projeto PHP, unica até então com acesso externo liberado. Semana passada precisei criar uma pasta dentro do www com as assinaturas dos emails dos funcionários, e o arquivo de log nesse momento está cheio, pois em cada email recebido daqui ele salva no log do Apache:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma forma de "dividir" o log do Apache, um para cada projeto na pasta WWW? Ou até mesmo desabilitar o log para o projeto "Assinaturas"?

Update: Versão do Apache

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Na pasta `bin` do Apache existe o [rotatelogs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/rotatelogs.html)

Esse programa é útil para gerar logs rotatórios.

## Apache rotatelogs

Aqui um exemplo de como gerar 1 arquivo de log por dia:

```
<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\"" combined
    CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe C:/www/site/logs/access/log_access-%Y-%m-%d.txt 86400 +000" combined env=!dontlog
</IfModule>
```

Observações:

1. Mesmo sob ambiente Windows, o caminho deve usar barra normal.

2. O caminho do rotatelogs deve ser relativo, em ambiente Windows, e deve iniciar com a barra vertical `|`.

```
C:/www/site/...
```

**Não** faça com barra invertida:

```
C:\www\site\...
```

Os logs serão gerados de acordo com o formato `log_access-%Y-%m-%d.txt`

```
log_access-2016-08-29.txt
log_access-2016-08-30.txt
log_access-2016-08-31.txt
```

Também pode restringir pelo tamanho do arquivo. Por exemplo, gerar um novo arquivo de log a cada 1mb. Consulte as opções na documentação: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/rotatelogs.html

## Caso queira apenas desativar:

```
#CustomLog "|bin/rotat...
```

Um simples sharp (#) desativa a linha.

obs: Normalmente num ambiente de desenvolvimento não há muita razão para salvar logs de acesso usando os recursos de log do Apache.

O mais interessante pode ser salvar logs de erro. Para isso segue a mesma forma. Apenas aplique-a para o parâmetro `ErrorLog`.

```
ErrorLog  "|bin/rotatelogs.exe C:/www/site/logs/errors/log_error-%Y-%m-%d.txt 86400 +000"
```

O mesmo aplica-se para ambiente Linux. Apenas modifica o caminho do rotatelog

Windows: `|bin/rotatelogs.exe`

Linux: `bin/rotatelogs`

<sub>Para obter maior proveitos das funcionalidades, recomendo que organize cada projeto num virtualhost independente ao invés de organizá-los num único virtualhost separados por pastas.</sub>